# Why is the gas price so low even though daily transactions have not decreased

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, price

The Ethereum gas price is currently about 6 gwei, the lowest I've seen it in a very long time. It was over 100 gwei most of the time for over a year I think.

However daily transactions on the network don't seem to have decreased much at all. There are still about 1 million to 1.2 million transactions happening per day according to https://etherscan.io/chart/tx.

What is the difference that is causing the gas price to be lower now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a supply/demand equation.  Blocks are pretty much full, so you can't add too many txns to that chart.  But if people are more ok with slower transactions, they won't be bidding up the gas price and the numbers will fall.

https://etherscan.io/chart/networkutilization. (50% is 100% post 1559 (doubled the size, but targets 50%....confusing I know))